# Вставка RadioButton в стиль шаблона

Tags: css3

Не могу поставить RADIOBUTTON в стиль одного темплейта, вечно всплывают какие-то подводные камни.

Моя задача состоит в том, что нужно создать один шаблон с рисунка (Index.png)
У меня все получилось, кроме расстановки RADIOBUTTON (первичный вид, вид при наведении мишки, вид при нажатии кнопки) (они отображены icons.png) пользоваться можно только вызовом и реализовать их через css, разрезать мне их нельзя. 
реализовать при помощи{background-position-ом}не вышло у меня.
Я вызывал этот стиль в необходимых мне селекторах

1. background:   url(icons.png) 0  53px  repeat-y;

радиобаттоны становятся на место, но пропадает сам фон списка, на которую наводиться мышка или нажимается

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете вставить эти радиобатонs и загрузить их не разрезая рисунок.

Для того что бы найти быстро разобраться с кодом, с меньшей потерей Вашего времени я пометил участки стиля в файле consumer.css
- Нажатая кнопка в стиле помечена `/*----button-push---*/`
- Кнопки в спокойном состоянии `/*---all----buttons---*/`
- Кнопки, на которые наведен курсор `/*-----knopka-kursor------*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html { background: #f7f7f7; }
body { margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; line-height: 160%; font-family: "Verdana"; }
#wrapper { margin: 0px; }
#inner {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
.variant {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.variant span { background: url("assets/icons.png") 2px -173px no-repeat; display: block; width: 25px; height: 15px; float: left; }
.variant:hover span { background: url("assets/icons.png") 2px -205px no-repeat; }
.variant:hover { background: #e4e7f1; cursor: pointer; }
.checked, .checked:hover { background: #9eafc3; color: #FFF; }
.checked span, .checked:hover span { background: url("assets/icons.png") 2px -189px no-repeat; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="variant checked"><span></span>0:</div>
        <div class="variant"><span></span>1:</div>
        <div class="variant"><span></span>2:</div>
        <div class="variant"><span></span>3:</div>
        <div class="variant"><span></span>4:</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

В людских браузерах отображает норм радиобуты! дукрутить остальное и будет счястье))

Comment: Все идеально=) спасибо тебе большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста) учись)

Answer (score 1):

```
.blue.button, .blue.button:visited { background-color: #56789d; }
.blue.button:hover { background-color: #5f80a3; }
```

Ну вот у тебя тут фоны кнопок, в чем проблема?

Ну и плюс ты в код не вставил ни одной RADIOBUTTON.

Comment: Srek's- ты не совсем правильно понял проблема не в кнопке blue.button
проблема в том как разместить RADIOBUTTON. применяя background-position в css над каждым пунктом опросника, скачай архив еще раз я подчистил код убрал все лишнее что бы не сбило с толку